# How to set large number of items in ViewFlipper in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper and an ImageView in it.I have large number of Images with me to load to the Imageview at run time.If the number of images is less its working fine.How can i achieve Image flipping with large number of images.Please help.

Comment: please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264819/images-memory-management-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. If you are aiming at Honeycomb and newer advices use AdapterViewFlipper instead. You can pretty search/replace ViewFlipper for AdapterViewFlipper in your code (many methods are shared between the two), and then of course you need to pair it with an adapter extended from BaseAdapter. I did not find a lot of examples of doing so that were specific to AdapterViewFlipper, but the process is largely the same as for GridView, ListView, etc. This brief example helped get me going: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/.